# Share text + image url in twitter - Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, twitter

I am developing a WP8 application where i need to post some tweets. The tweet should contain text and image url where the image should be automatically loaded from the image url.

Right now I can able to share only the text. I dont find any thing to share the image url as well.

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest
            {
                Credentials = credentials,
                Path = "/1.1/statuses/update.json",
                Method = WebMethod.Post
            };

            restRequest.AddParameter("status", "test4");
            restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.